# Converting Postgres interval to Haskell NominalTimeDiff with postgresql-simple

Tags: postgresql, haskell, time

I (think I) need [FromField](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-FromField.html#t:FromField) and [ToField](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.4.10.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-ToField.html) instances for [NominalDiffTime](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html), in order to interface with a Postgres table with a column of type `interval`.

I've found the [interval](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.4.10.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-TypeInfo-Static.html#v:interval) TypeInfo and am in the process of figuring out how to interface with `TypeInfo`, but hopefully there is an easier way?

Comment: I see now that a `ToField` instance exists, it's just `FromField` that's missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, there are reasons not to provide such an instance. `NominalDiffTime` doesn't sensibly represent all values of `interval`. For example, `2 days` is different from `48 hours`. Particularly, `1 year` can't be expressed in days.

Here's a `FromField` instance for `NominalDiffTime` that fails for intervals with components that are larger than an hour (something like 25:00:00 is ok, though).

```
instance FromField NominalDiffTime where
    fromField f mdat =
        if typeOid f /= typoid interval
            then returnError Incompatible f ""
            else case mdat of
                Nothing  -> returnError UnexpectedNull f ""
                Just dat -> case parseOnly (nominalDiffTime <* endOfInput) dat of
                    Left msg  -> returnError ConversionFailed f msg
                    Right t   -> return t


nominalDiffTime :: Parser NominalDiffTime
nominalDiffTime = do
    (h, m, s) <- interval
    return . fromRational . toRational $ s + 60*(fromIntegral m) + 60*60*(fromIntegral h)

-- | Parse a limited postgres interval of the form [-]HHH:MM:SS.[SSSS] (no larger units than hours).
interval :: Parser (Int, Int, Pico)
interval = do
    h <- signed decimal <* char ':'
    m <- twoDigits <* char ':'
    s <- seconds
    if m < 60 && s <= 60
        then return (h, m, s)
        else fail "invalid interval"

-- functions below borrowed from postgresql-simple
seconds :: Parser Pico
twoDigits :: Parser Int
```

Comment: Yep, this is exactly why postgresql-simple doesn't contain an out-of-box `FromField` instance for `NominalDiffTime`.    On the other hand,  it would be nice to implement some sort of Haskell type that could faithfully represent postgresql's interval type.   And limited instance along these lines might be useful,  but I haven't given it much thought.

Comment: (Also, as an aside,  the reason why `2 days` isn't the same thing as `48 hours` is because in every timezone ever used by everyday people, not all days are 24 hours long.   (And the customer probably wants local time)   Most exceptions are 23 hours or 25 hours during daylight savings shifts,  but not all;  see the IANA tz database for a list of these oddballs.)